# Flutter: Is it possible to scroll only items inside ExpansionPanelRadio body:?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scrollable

I am new to flutter and would appreciate if someone could give me some hints on this:
I have to make few (not fixed number of) widgets which have to be expandable.
When expanded, they contain list of widgets in their body. List is long and it has to be scrollable in order to see all items.

If I put everything (whole expandable widget) inside `SingleChildScrollView` list items in body are scrollable, but also headers scroll - which I should prevent.

```
  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: item.id,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.network(
                          "https://some_picture.svg",
                          height: 80),
                      Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text(' Some Text'),
                        Text(' label '), 
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ));
            },
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widgets.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: widgets[index]),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ));
      }).toList(),
    ));
  }
```

and if I put only body inside `SingleChildScrollView` like this, then I got Exceptions.

```
Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: item.id,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.network("https://some_picture.svg",
                          height: 80),
                      Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text(' Some Text'),
                        Text(' label '),
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ));
            },
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widgets.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: widgets[index]),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            )));
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Is it possible to scroll only list items and to keep header in fixed position?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height` for your `body` and remove `physics`, `shrinkWrap` in order to get what you want, like this:

```
body: SizedBox(
  height: 300,//<-- add this
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widgets.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
        ListTile(title: widgets[index]),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  ),
),
```

Comment: was it what you want? @NoZiffer